# Oracle SQL get hierarchy of all children

Tags: sql, oracle, hierarchical-data, oracle19c

I have a table containing elements referencing their parent.

#### Nodes

| ID | PARENT_ID |
| --- | --- |
| 2002 | 2009 |
| 2003 | 2009 |
| 2007 | 2010 |
| 2008 | 2010 |
| 2009 | 2010 |
| 2010 | NULL |

To get the immediate children I use

```sql
SELECT n.ID as ID, n.PARENT_ID as PARENT_ID,
    (
        SELECT listagg(pn.ID,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY id) as CHILD_IDS 
        FROM NODES pn 
        WHERE pn.PARENT_ID = n.ID
    ) as CHILD_IDS  
FROM NODES n
```

#### RESULT

| ID | PARENT_ID | CHILD_IDs |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2002 | 2009 | NULL |
| 2003 | 2009 | NULL |
| 2007 | 2010 | NULL |
| 2008 | 2010 | NULL |
| 2009 | 2010 | 2002,2003 |
| 2010 | NULL | 2007,2008,2009 |

But I need the hierarchical structure of children, ideally some structure similar to a JSON object. E.g. for the node `2010` the ideal result should be

```json
[
  {
    2007: []
  },
  {
    2008: []
  },
  {
    2009: [
      {
        2002: []
      },
      {
        2003: []
      },
    ]
  }
]
```

How can I create a structure similar to this?
I don't really know where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's hierarchical query; if you want to see it indented, then here's one option:

Sample data:

```
SQL> with test (id, parent_id) as
  2  (select
  3   2002, 2009 from dual union all select
  4   2003, 2009 from dual union all select
  5   2007, 2010 from dual union all select
  6   2008, 2010 from dual union all select
  7   2009, 2010 from dual union all select
  8   2010, null from dual
  9  )
```

Query:

```
 10  select lpad(' ', 2 * level - 1) || id as id
 11  from test
 12  start with parent_id is null
 13  connect by prior id = parent_id;

ID
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 2010
   2007
   2008
   2009
     2002
     2003

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This looks promising. I have multiple nodes where parent_id is null. Is there a good way to identify the root node from an individual entry? Besides looking at the indentation and finding the first non-indented node?

Comment: You're welcome. In that case, you have to START WITH *something*. If you already know which parent node you want, then modify line #12 to `start with parent_id = 2010` (or any other value).